# Pandas organise delimited rows of data frame into dictionary

Tags: numpy, pandas

After reading a cvs file with pandas by:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, names= ['x', 'y', 'z'], header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

print df
```

Outputs something like:

```
             x        y        z
0          ROW   1.0000      NaN
1      60.1662  30.5987 -29.2246
2      60.1680  30.5951 -29.2212
3      60.1735  30.5843 -29.2101
4          ROW   2.0000      NaN
5      60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664
6          ROW   3.0000      NaN
7      60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664
8      60.1958  30.5412 -29.1665         
9      60.1965  30.5419 -29.1667
```

now ideally I would like to organise all the data with the assumption that everything below a "ROW" entry row in the data frame belongs to each other. Maybe I would like a dictionary of python arrays so that

```
dict = {ROW1: [[60.1662  30.5987 -29.2246], [60.1680  30.5951 -29.2212], [60.1735  30.5843 -29.2101]], ROW2: [[60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664]], ... }
```

basically each dictionary entry is a numpy array of the coordinates in the data frame. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like we need some dictionary comprehension here:

```
In [162]:

print df

         x        y        z
0      ROW   1.0000      NaN
1  60.1662  30.5987 -29.2246
2  60.1680  30.5951 -29.2212
3  60.1735  30.5843 -29.2101
4      ROW   2.0000      NaN
5  60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664
6      ROW   3.0000      NaN
7  60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664
8  60.1958  30.5412 -29.1665
9  60.1965  30.5419 -29.1667

In [163]:

df['label'] = df.ix[df.x=='ROW', ['x','y']].apply(lambda x: x[0]+'%i'%x[1], axis=1)

In [164]:

df.label.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
df = df.dropna().set_index('label')

In [165]:

{k: df.ix[k].values.tolist() for k in df.index.unique()}

Out[165]:

{'ROW1': [['60.1662', 30.5987, -29.2246],
  ['60.1680', 30.5951, -29.2212],
  ['60.1735', 30.5843, -29.2101]],
 'ROW2': [['60.1955', 30.541, -29.1664]],
 'ROW3': [['60.1955', 30.541, -29.1664],
  ['60.1958', 30.5412, -29.1665],
  ['60.1965', 30.5419, -29.1667]]}
```

Comment: Great! Except I don't have the label in my original df... is there a way around that?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error, `label` column was generated from line 163, fixed.

Comment: How does the `df.label.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)` method assign a label number that corresponds to the which "ROW" the data is under?

Comment: After line 163, only the 0, 4 and 6 rows has values in the `label` column (`'ROW1' 'ROW2' 'ROW3'`), the other cells are `nan`s. Therefore we want to fill the `nan` using the last valid value, which is the `'pad'` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
df['label'] = (df.x == 'ROW').astype(int).cumsum()

Out[24]: 
         x        y        z  label
0      ROW   1.0000      NaN      1
1  60.1662  30.5987 -29.2246      1
2  60.1680  30.5951 -29.2212      1
3  60.1735  30.5843 -29.2101      1
4      ROW   2.0000      NaN      2
5  60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664      2
6      ROW   3.0000      NaN      3
7  60.1955  30.5410 -29.1664      3
8  60.1958  30.5412 -29.1665      3
9  60.1965  30.5419 -29.1667      3
```

And then, by `groupby` on label column, you can start to process the df whatever you like. You have all the column name within each group. Very convenient to work on.

Comment: I was just writing up something similar, although remember that you don't need to actually add the column `label` -- you can use `df.groupby((df["x"] == "ROW").cumsum()` equally easily.  Often it's handy to have it to look at, though, I'll admit. :-)

Comment: Much agreed. Thanks. :)